# How to show a feedback message in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, label, urllib2, feedback

I want to show a message when the user pressed a button in a tkinter gui app , the program works fine ( it has a entry type for user input, search a  song lyric using urllib2 and shows the text in an entry ), but after pressed the button the program frezzes until the urllib makes the request, and i can't show a message

This is the button that listen events

```
self.button = Button(text="search",padx=4, pady=4, command=self.get_lyric)
self.button.pack()
```

And the method that listen that event

```
def get_lyric(self):
    #LYRICS.COM
    self.feedback.config(text="loading...")

    site= str(self.get_googlesearch_link(self.input_text.get()))
    #print site
    page = urllib2.urlopen(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    main = soup.find(id="lyric_space")
    # show lyrics
```

I tried with a label , but the message appears after the urllib response, what can i do for solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to thread the different actions.  Python will only handle one action at a time unless you create a new thread for the secondary action to occur.

Try:

```
import thread

def button1():
    self.button = Button(text="search",padx=4, pady=4, command=self.get_lyric)
    self.button.pack()

def get_lyric(self):
    #LYRICS.COM
    self.feedback.config(text="loading...")

    site= str(self.get_googlesearch_link(self.input_text.get()))
    #print site
    page = urllib2.urlopen(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    main = soup.find(id="lyric_space")

thread.start_new_thread(button1, ())
thread.start_new_thread(get_lyrics, ())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm tried the code but the program don't work, I have a lot to learn about threading( i'm usually use javascript that only have one thread )